# Observer is not working after next(undefined)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable

I have an currentUser$ in AccountService;

```
 private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
 currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();
```

In login method:

```
this.currentUserSource.next(user);
```

In Logout method:

```
this.currentUserSource.next(undefined);
```

In Auth Guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
  map(user  => {
    if(user){
     return true;
    }
    this.toastr.error('Unauthorized');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    return false;
  }));
```

}

Now problem is once I am login Auth guard is working fine but after logout I try to open the same route and it gives me blank screen.
Can anybody check what I am doing wrong?

Route:

```
path: '',
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
children: [
  { path: 'users', component: UserListComponent}]
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~12.1.2",
"@angular/common": "~12.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.1.2",
"@angular/core": "~12.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "~12.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.2",
"@angular/router": "~12.1.2",
"@kolkov/ngx-gallery": "^1.2.3",
"@schematics/angular": "^9.1.0",
"bootstrap": "4.1.1",
"bootswatch": "^5.0.2",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
"ngx-spinner": "^12.0.0",
"ngx-timeago": "^2.0.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^14.0.0",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^1.9.3",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"},
```

Console:

```
[WDS] Disconnected! polyfills.js:9720:9
close https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9720
initSocket https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9890
dispatchEvent https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1893
_close https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2774
timer https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12878
invokeTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10723
runTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10495
invokeTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10804
invoke https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10793
0 https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12858
(Async: setTimeout handler)
scheduleTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12860
scheduleTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10710
scheduleTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10538
scheduleMacroTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10561
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10996
setNative https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12902
name https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11292
_close https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2763
_transportClose https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2716
g https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1778
emit https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1802
onclose https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4981
wrapFn https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11080
invokeTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10723
runTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10495
invokeTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10804
invokeTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11917
globalZoneAwareCallback https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11943
(Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
customScheduleGlobal https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12069
scheduleTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10710
scheduleTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10538
scheduleEventTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10564
makeAddListener https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12224
set https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11141
WebSocketTransport https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4979
_connect https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2620
_receiveInfo https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2595
g https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1778
emit https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1802
doXhr https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2339
g https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1778
emit https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1802
InfoAjax https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2123
g https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1778
emit https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1802
onreadystatechange https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3443
wrapFn https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11080
invokeTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10723
runTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10495
invokeTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10804
invokeTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11917
globalZoneAwareCallback https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11943
(Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
customScheduleGlobal https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12069
scheduleTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10710
scheduleTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10538
scheduleEventTask https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10564
makeAddListener https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:12224
```

This is what I am getting in console but I think this is not an issue in my case.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I would personally use a BehaviorSubject in this scenario. Also any reason your calling asObservable() on a subject that is usable as an observable already? 

Another thought, though I have no idea if this would or wouldn't cause it because I never use undefined directly. But try returning null instead.

Comment: @Gavin on null i am getting compile time error "Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User | undefined'."

Comment: @MikeOne I have added console log. Please check

Comment: Appears to be a known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16211 You can try the various workarounds listed there... Perhaps [returning a `UrlTree`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16211#issuecomment-570815716)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am already returning URL in map please check, I tried to do console.log inside map but after login I see info of user in log but as upon logout it did not go inside map and doesn't log anything.

Comment: Please click the link to the comment that discusses returning a `UrlTree` to see what I mean. You are not "returning URL"; you literally have `return false;` in the code. In any case, it looks like an issue in Angular that has not been fixed; that link has a bunch of workarounds but it does require you to read them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I had different issue than the link you had shared, anyway Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it in Auth guard by using take(1).

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
let isUser = false;
this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((user) => {
  if (user) isUser = true;
});

if (isUser) return of(true);
else {
  this.toastr.error('Unauthorized');
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  return of(false);
}}}
```

Comment: This will always return `false` if `account.currentUser$` returns the value asynchronously.  Instead of subscribing to the observable, you should use the [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator to transform the result of `accountService.currentUser$` (`Observable<User>`) to `Observable<boolean>`.  You can use the [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) operator to perform your side effect logic.  The result could look something  like [this](https://pasteboard.co/KhwuKgC.png)